# How do I "listen" to eclipse actions. I'm specific interested in the Build Action

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Is it possible to subscribe to users' interaction with the eclipse environment? In my example, I need to run my plugin's code when the user builds his or hers projects. I'm very new to plugin development and I'm really lost (eclipse help documentation doesn't help a bit).

**EDIT** to clarify (because someone marked my question as a duplicate) I wish to listen to all user's actions, and I'm *particularly* interested in the Build Action. If possible, I also wanted to listen to things like refactorings and the creation of new types, but right now I'm worried about Build. Can I listen to it and get some sort of "Build Results"?

Comment: What do mean by 'Build Results'? You can listen to resource changes which will tell you about every file being added/changed/deleted.

Comment: @greg-449 Nice, thanks for the reply. how do I do that? does it include the case when the user simply builds the project?

Comment: You use `IResourceChangeListener` [see here](https://eclipse.org/articles/Article-Resource-deltas/resource-deltas.html). This tells you about every change made to every file in the workspace by anything.

Comment: @greg-449 Thank you very much.